# ¿Como monitorear un log con jquery o alguna libreria dinamica?

Tags: php, jquery, phalcon

Hola quiero monitorear la infomacion almacenada en un log sobre los eventos realizados en mi sistema. Crear el archivo .log mediante phalcon ya puedo pero de que manera lo visualizo que se ha de una manera dinamica q se actualize sin necesidad de actualizar la pagina si no cuando se ingrese un nuevo dato

Answer (score 1):

Hola yo te recomendaría que usuaras AJAX y PHP, me explico:
Generar una iteración cada X segundos mediante javascript, dicha iteración debe llamar via AJAX a un archivo PHP que sea el encargado de verificar si el log ha cambiado. En el caso de que haya cambiado, que te devuelva los nuevos valores. Y actualices solo la parte del HTML que necesite.